# How to ping a pc through an ICS

Tags: networking, ping, ics

I'm trying to ping a PC that is connected to the network through an ICS. For example, I'm trying to ping PC02 from PC03. How would I do that? And is this even possible?

```
PC01(192.168.178.2)---ICS---PC02(192.168.137.85)
|
| PC03(192.168.178.3)
| |
R0/DHCP
|
|
internet
```

Comment: What OS is running on PC01 and PC02?

Comment: PC03 is running windows 8.1, PC02 is running windows 10 and PC01 is running windows server 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. I'm pretty sure you cannot ping the PC02 from PC03. This is because PC01 and PC02 form one local network and PC01 and PC03 form another local network.

So actually, PC02 and PC03 are not part of the same network. This can also be seen by checking the 3rd number in it's IP. Also, if you go to PC01 and check it's local IP, it'll actually have 2 local IPs.

So in short, no, I don't think it's possible to ping the PC02 from PC03